# Regular two-dimensional algebraic spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-spaces

Let $X$ be an algebraic space which is integral, noetherian, separated, two-dimensional and regular. We keep these assumptions throughout.

> **Question 1.** Is $X$ always a scheme?
> **Question 2.** If $X$ is a scheme, does it have an ample invertible sheaf?

**Some context.** The similar questions in dimension $1$ have a positive answer, even without the regular condition; see Stacks Project, Tags [0ADD](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ADD) and [09NZ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09NZ).

Artin [1, Théorème 4.7] has shown that the answers to questions 1 and 2 are positive if $X$ is of finite type over a field.
On the other hand, there are singular two-dimensional algebraic spaces, proper over a field, which are not schemes, and others which are non-projective schemes. Non-normal examples are fairly easy to construct by attaching closed subschemes in a weird way. Normal ones typically involve contractions; see [1, Exemple 4.4] for the first type and [2] for the second type.

It is proved in Stacks Project, Tag [0C5N](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C5N) that if our $X$ is a scheme of finite type over a noetherian scheme $S$, then it is quasiprojective over $S$. Using similar constructions, I can remove the scheme assumption on $X$, but I still need the base scheme $S$, which I find a bit frustrating.

**Related questions.** Ultimately, everything relies on the following problem:

> **Question 3.** Let $x\in X$ be a closed point, and let $X_1\to X$ be the blowing up at $x$. Assume $X_1$ is a scheme (resp. has an ample sheaf). Does the same hold for $X$?

In the Stacks Project, the problem is approached by starting with $X_1$ and the exceptional divisor $E$, and constructing a (quasiprojective) "contraction" of $E$ by projective methods. It is then easy to see that this contraction must be $X$. The fact that $X_1$ is quasiprojective over a scheme is essential in the construction.

The following interesting question may or may not help:

> **Question 4.** Let $L$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$. Is $L$ Zariski-locally trivial?

According to Schröer [3], this does not always hold for proper (non-normal) algebraic spaces over a field. The question seems open in the regular case, even in dimension 2.

[1] M. Artin, Théorèmes de représentabilité pour les espaces algébriques, Presses de l'université de Montréal, 1973.
[2] S. Schröer, On non-projective normal surfaces, Manuscripta Math. 100, 317–321 (1999).
[3] S. Schröer, Hilbert's Theorem 90 and algebraic spaces, Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra, Volume 173, Issue 3, 2002, Pages 339-345.

Comment: Similar questions where asked here: https://www.math.columbia.edu/~dejong/wordpress/?p=4115 No answers unfortunately.

Comment: @Johan: Thanks, Johan, I had missed that (or perhaps forgotten).